# If localstorage empty do nothing. If not, do something

Tags: javascript, html

Would I be able to create a function that automatically runs when something is put into localstorage?

I tried to come up with something myself but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function () {
    if (localStorage.value == ""){
        //do nothing
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "" + (localStorage.getItem("server")) + ""  ;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This bit of code works, but it doesn't update itself, so if I enter a new value into localstorage, this code won't pick it up and will display the old value still.

```
if (localStorage.length == 0){   
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Please go back and enter your name.";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "" + (localStorage.getItem("server")) + ""  ;
}
```

Comment: Look up the `onstorage` event.

Comment: check `localStorage.length == 0` ? if I understood you correctly

Comment: Basically on another page a user can input their name into a text field and save it into localstorage.
So on this page I want it to display that name if a value is there, if not, do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote a wrapper around localStorage and used that instead set you could run a callback when a value is set

```
var storage = {
   get: function(key){
      return localStorage.getItem(key);
   },
   set: function(key, value, callback){
      localStorage.setItem(key, value);
      if(typeof(callback) === 'function'){
          callback.call(null, value);
      }
   }
}

storage.set('user', "John Smith", function(value){
    console.log("You set your username to %s", value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to find out if localstorage is empty.

```
if (localStorage.length == 0){ ...
```

Comment: yes thank you this does work, sort of.
In order for the else statement to work I must refresh the browser. Which I don't want to do

Comment: What do you mean ? What is your else statement ?

Comment: Things are becoming confusing. It looks like your else should work, but you'd like to update your element whenever the value of localstorage changes. But that is not what your question states.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use `setInterval` to refresh itself.

```
if (localStorage.length == 0){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Please go back and enter your name.";
}
else {
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, 1000);
    function myTimer() {
        var nameprint = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML ="" + (localStorage.getItem("server")) + "";
    }
}
```